# Hibernate not retriveing data; Class is not mapped

Tags: hibernate, web-applications

[image: Project structure]

#### Source package:

[image: Source files]

#### hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mkastrive</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">mkastrive</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>

    <mapping resource="n/a/mkastrive/UserPojoMap.hbm.xml" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

UserPojoMap.hbm.xml - located inside n.a.mkastrive package.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="n.a.mkastrive.UserPojo" table="user" lazy="false">    
        <id name="id" type="integer">
            <column name="id" />
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" type="string">
            <column name="firstName" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>

        <property name="lastName" type="string">
            <column name="lastName" not-null="true" />
        </property>

        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Struts2's actions calls this function from the execute()

```
private List<UserPojo> userPojo = null;

    private void listUser() throws HibernateException {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getAttribute(HibernateListener.KEY_NAME);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from " + UserPojo.class.getSimpleName() + " where id = :id ");
        query.setParameter("id", "1");
        List list = query.list();
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
        userPojo = session.createCriteria(UserPojo.class).list();
//      System.out.println("userPojo.size: " + userPojo.size());
//      for (int i = 0; i < userPojo.size(); i++) {
//          System.out.println(userPojo.get(i).getEmail());
//      }       
    }
```

I'm not getting any exception; it's just the list is empty, 0 elements.

#### Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>n.a.mkastrive</groupId>
    <artifactId>MkaStrive</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MkaStrive Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>MkaStrive</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/CounterWebApp</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[image: Database]

Actually, this does give me an exception:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from " + UserPojo.class.getSimpleName() + " where id = :id ");
```

#### Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserPojo is not mapped [from UserPojo where id = :id ]
```

Update 1: HibernateListener

```
package n.a.mkastrive.listner;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;


public class HibernateListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private Configuration config;
    private SessionFactory factory;
    private String path = "/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static Class clazz = HibernateListener.class;

    public static final String KEY_NAME = clazz.getName();

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        SessionFactory sf = (SessionFactory) sce.getServletContext().getAttribute("SessionFactory");
        sf.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();

        /**
         * Connection Information..
         */
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkastrive");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "****");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "****");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        /**
         * Mapping Resources..
         */
        config.addResource("n/a/mkastrive/User.hbm.xml");
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sf = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute(KEY_NAME, sf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build configuration programmatically. At least this worked for me.

```
    // build the config
    cfg = new Configuration();

    /**
     * Connection Information..
     */
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", ">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mkastrive");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "mkastrive");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "****");
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

    /**
     * Mapping Resources..
     */
    cfg.addResource("n/a/mkastrive/UserPojoMap.hbm.xml");

    sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: This worked... but why isn't the xml configuration not working?

Comment: You didn't provide the code for building a session factory. Probably you are missing configuration file or property used to map the resource.